Can't take camera permission on webview in .NET MAUI Android
I'm opening a webview in Android in .Net MAUI. But I can't show the camera and take a photo. I declared yet the permissions in Android Manifest as you can see:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon.svg" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-sdk />
</manifest>

In MainActivity.cs I have:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Plugin.Permissions;


namespace RepoClick2
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Solicitar permiso para la cámara
            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera }, 0);
            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (requestCode == 0 && grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                // El permiso fue concedido
            }
            else
            {
                // El permiso fue denegado
            }
        }


    }
}

So I had tried this:
#if ANDROID
using Android.Webkit;
#endif

namespace RepoClick2
{
    public partial class RepoWeb : ContentPage
    {
        public RepoWeb()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

#if ANDROID
            // Configuración del WebView para permitir la cámara
            webView.HandlerChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (webView.Handler.PlatformView is Android.Webkit.WebView androidWebView)
                {
                    androidWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    androidWebView.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;
                    androidWebView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                    androidWebView.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;

                    // Configuración de WebChromeClient para manejar permisos de la cámara
                    androidWebView.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
                }
            };
#endif
        }

#if ANDROID
        public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
        {
            public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
            {
                // Aceptar automáticamente todas las solicitudes de permiso
                request.Grant(request.GetResources());
            }
        }
#endif

The above code is inside a xaml page in which I am showing my webview after a successful login in to my app.
I also had tried a lot of code but no right results.

Is there any error log?

Where can i find error log?

In Output. In addition, try the code of this issue: WebView Does Not Accept Permissions That Are Already Granted.
